# ReactJS Passing state from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following and was wondering if there is a more ellegant way to pass the `this.state.currentSection` state to `<HeaderButton />`?:

```
...
render() {
        return <div>
            <div className="section" style={this.state.currentSection === 'SPECIAL' ? {} : {'opacity': '0.4'}}>
                <HeaderButton active={this.state.currentSection === 'SPECIAL'} text="Special" count={23} backgoundColor={'#c04c36'} onClick={this.setActiveSpecial}/>
            </div>
...
```

Comment: 1. You are not passing `this.state.currentSection` but a comparison with this variable. 2. What do you mean by *elegant* ?

Comment: You are right, I mean is there a better way than doing two ternary ifs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could destructure the `this.state` in the render method like this

```
render() {
  const { currentSection } = this.state;
  const isActive = (currentSection === 'SPECIAL');
  return (
   <div className="section" style={isActive ? {} : {'opacity': '0.4'}}>
     <HeaderButton active={isActive} text="Special" count={23} backgoundColor={'#c04c36'} onClick={this.setActiveSpecial}/>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single variable for this instead of writing `this.state.currentSection` 2 times. `Boolean(null) === false`

```
render() {
        let value = (this.state.currentSection === "SPECIAL") ? null : {opacity:'0.4'}; 
        return (<div>
            <div className="section" style={value}>
                <HeaderButton active={Boolean(value)} text="Special" count={23} backgoundColor={'#c04c36'} onClick={this.setActiveSpecial}/>
            </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript [spread notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
render() {
    const headerButtonState = {
          active:this.state.currentSection === 'SPECIAL',
          text:"Special",
          count:23, 
          backgoundColor:'#c04c36'
    }
    return <div>
            <div className="section" style={this.state.currentSection === 'SPECIAL' ? {} : {'opacity': '0.4'}}>
                <HeaderButton {...headerButtonState} onClick={this.setActiveSpecial}/>
            </div>
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle only one condition, instead of ternary use &&.

ie, instead of:

```
isActive ? <Component/> : null;
```

use:

```
isActive && <Component/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify all the style-related stuff in css based on the section's `--special` class modifier.

```js
import classnames from 'classnames';

...

render() {
  const { currentSection } = this.state;
  const isSectionSpecial = currentSection === 'SPECIAL';

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classnames('section', {
        'section--special': isSectionSpecial
      })}>
        <HeaderButton active={isSectionSpecial} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.section {
  ...
}

.section--special {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.header-button {
  ...
}

.section--special .header-button {
  background-color: #c04c36;
}
```